# Spring Boot Maven resource finding not working correctly

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm currently working on JPA layer on my Spring Boot app, but have issue to properly test Spring's JPA repositories. I keep getting errors that suggest the resource sql files was not found when the tests are starting. I'm using Maven with my project and @Sql annotation to prepopulate test database before actual tests are running.

I have placed my sql files under standard maven resources directory:
[image]

These are my test module:

```
@Sql(scripts={"/sql/02_create_tables.sql", "/sql/test_repository_data.sql"})
@DataJpaTest
public class ExpenditureRecordRepositoryTest {

    private static String STORED_BANK_STATEMENT_ID = "062022";
    private static String NOT_EXISTING_BANK_STATEMENT_ID = "not_existing_bsid";

    private static Integer STORED_EXPENDITURE_CATEGORY_ID = 1;

    private static String NOT_EXISTING_RECORD_NAME = "not_existing_record";
    private static String STORED_RECORD_NAME = "record1";
    private static String STORED_RECORD_NAME2 = "record2";
    private static String STORED_RECORD_NAME3 = "record3";
    private static String STORED_RECORD_NAME4 = "record4";

    @Autowired
    private ExpenditureRecordRepository repository;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should return all stored records")
    public void testFindAll() {
        List<ExpenditureRecord> entities = repository.findAll();

        assertThat(entities.size()).isEqualTo(4);

        ExpenditureRecord record = entities.get(0);
        assertEquals(10.0, record.getAmount());
        assertEquals(STORED_RECORD_NAME, record.getName());
        assertEquals(STORED_BANK_STATEMENT_ID, record.getBankStatementId());
        assertEquals(STORED_EXPENDITURE_CATEGORY_ID, record.getCategoryId());

        record = entities.get(1);
        assertEquals(8.0, record.getAmount());
        assertEquals(STORED_RECORD_NAME2, record.getName());
        assertEquals(STORED_BANK_STATEMENT_ID, record.getBankStatementId());
        assertEquals(STORED_EXPENDITURE_CATEGORY_ID, record.getCategoryId());

        record = entities.get(2);
        assertEquals(5.0, record.getAmount());
        assertEquals(STORED_RECORD_NAME3, record.getName());
        assertEquals(STORED_BANK_STATEMENT_ID, record.getBankStatementId());
        assertEquals(STORED_EXPENDITURE_CATEGORY_ID, record.getCategoryId());

        record = entities.get(3);
        assertEquals(11.0, record.getAmount());
        assertEquals(STORED_RECORD_NAME4, record.getName());
        assertEquals(STORED_BANK_STATEMENT_ID, record.getBankStatementId());
        assertEquals(STORED_EXPENDITURE_CATEGORY_ID, record.getCategoryId());
    }

    // other tests

}
```

This is my current pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl</groupId>
    <artifactId>intelligent.finance</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>intelligent.finance</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the error log:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [sql/02_create_tables.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [sql/02_create_tables.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist

    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:239)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.execute(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:269)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$4(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:279)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.lambda$executeWithoutResult$0(TransactionOperations.java:68)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:279)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$0(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:201)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:201)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:148)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:174)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:162)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [sql/02_create_tables.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getReader(EncodedResource.java:146)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.readScript(ScriptUtils.java:328)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:236)
    ... 68 more
```

The funny thing is that it was working before and I don't remember to change anything. Maybe I have problem in my environment?

I have also tested resouce finding with following methods:

- ExpenditureRecordRepositoryTest.class.getResourceAsStream
- @Value Resource
- ClassPathResource class
- using **classpath:*** as path for sql files

I will appreciate any kind of help with this!

BR

Comment: "The funny thing is that it was working before and I don't remember to change anything. Maybe I have problem in my environment?"
Is your project under source code control (git)? Can you see commit history, diff your source files since the last commit, revert to a prior state?

Comment: Unfortunetly no. I'm before initial commit on git. I planned to create repo after end of implementation of my first JPA's repo

Comment: Yeah, good idea to create the git repository up front, commit early and often.
Maybe you'll get some insight reading this, if you haven't already: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql